# Handle transaction on service layer using Java 8, Concurrency and Hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, concurrency, java-8

I'm implementing an web application using Java 8, Play Framework 2 and Hibernate 5. Currently a method in my generic Dao looks like this:

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T> {

  @Inject
  private JPAApi jpaApi;
  private Class<T> clazz;

  public GenericDao(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public CompletionStage<List<T>> save(T entity) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
      jpaApi.withTransaction((em) -> {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        return (int) session.save(entity);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Everything good so far, but I want to implement a layer service that handles the transactionality of the application. If I want to call to 2 saves on the service layer, I want both of them to be wrapped in the same transaction. This is a current service I have:

```
public class AttributeService extends CrudService<Attribute> implements IAttributeService {

  @Inject
  private AttributeDao attributeDao;
  @Inject
  private ItemDao itemDao;

  @Override
  public CompletionStage<Void> saveItemAttributes(int itemId, List<Attribute> attributes) {
    // need to call ItemDao.save and AttributeDao.save
    return null;
  }
}
```

Any recommendation on how to implement this architectural requirement?

Comment: did u ever used an EJB ?

Comment: I have. Don't I need a Java EE container to use that though? I'm using Play Framework by the way

Comment: Maybe that would be a useful info, and it's worth to be mentioned in your request body.
Anyways this can't exclude EJBs. You could take advantage of them through remote call.